# moving a model by frametime produces position errors

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, game-engine, game-physics

I have asked a similar question but i think i needed to be more clear on this.
Using Andriod and Open GL ES 2.0

This is my FrameTime Calculation

```
private long mCurrentTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()/1000; // set on entry to the render class
....

long mNewTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
float FrameTime = (mNewTime - mCurrentTime)/ 1000.0f;
mCurrentTime = mNewTime;
```

To move my model i now say something like

```
Model.MoveX(PositionX += Speed * FrameTime);
```

This moves the model fine.

If i move between 3 points lets say -10, 0, 10 after couple of moves the model appears to be in the wrong position. if i increase the speed the error becomes more noticeable.

What cause this error and how can i fix it.

below is the function for moving the cube

```
private float MinCubeMovement = -10.0f;
private float MaxCubeMovement = 10.0f;
private float Middle = 0.0f;
    private static boolean MoveLeftFlag = false;
private static boolean MoveRightFlag = false;
 private int PositionFlag = 0;
....

private void UpdatePlayer(float FrameTime)
{
    if(MoveLeftFlag == true)
    {
        if(PositionFlag == 0)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX >= MinCubeMovement)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(-CubeMoveSpeed * FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX <= MinCubeMovement)
            {

                PositionFlag = -1;
                MoveLeftFlag = false;
            }
        }
        if(PositionFlag == 1)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX >= Middle)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(-CubeMoveSpeed *  FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX <= Middle)
            {
                MoveLeftFlag = false;
                PositionFlag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(MoveRightFlag == true)
    {
        if(PositionFlag == 0)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX <= MaxCubeMovement)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(CubeMoveSpeed *  FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX >= MaxCubeMovement)
            {
                MoveRightFlag = false;
                PositionFlag = 1;
            }
        }
        if(PositionFlag == -1)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX <= Middle)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(CubeMoveSpeed * FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX >= Middle)
            {
                MoveRightFlag = false;
                PositionFlag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MoveLocalX adds a float to the positionX in my model class, this works fine

Comment: What are floats, and what are ints, what is your speed variable, - and since you are using time-based movement, how do you stop at the desired positions? Some more code would help, - it's impossible to say what the problem is based on the lines above, unless you forget to set mCurrentTime before the first loop.

Comment: @Terje I have added some more code above hopefully that will give you more to go off, note that all the rendering is fine so i have not added this.

Comment: I ran a test on the code, moved left and right until the flags were reset a few times, - and the positions remained approx. -10, 0, and 10.

Comment: mmm strange, is there anything i could be doing differently, if you put the speed up to 100 does it still work? I am pretty happy that the update code is working so that means maybe i have a problem with updating my model matrix or (possibly in the wrong order or wrong time) does this sound like something that could cause this

Comment: Do you ensure that it is not possible to set the MoveLeftFlag if the position <= MinCubeMovement? Also, inside checks like if(Cube1.PositionX <= MinCubeMovement) i would set Cube1.PositionX = MinCubeMovement;

Comment: Setting the Cube1.PositionX = MinCubeMovement; works but there is a tiny bounce every now and then. The MoveLeftFlag etc are set when either of the left or right buttons are pressed. Because the functions are called from the mainactivity code they have to be static but i cant put the model positions as static hence i used flags. What would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work, but I would debug the "FrameTime" variable if I were you, it sounds like it's not very constant. If it varies alot (and if you have another piece of code that increasingly strains the hardware), you'll end up with jittering an inexact timings after a while. Is the behaviour the same on the emulator as the phone?

Comment: I have looked at the values for frametime for around 2000 frames while i perform the movements all are between 0.016 - 0.022 average about 0.018, the only thing wrong with it is the starting frameTime which is about 435678.8, what should i initialise mCurrentTime to?

Comment: SystemClock.uptimeMillis() should be fine.